# INFORMIX: a count of each elementname from sub-query of distinct callid and the Max varable value

Tags: informix

Here are my tables:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I need to get a count of the elementname for each each callid where the varname equals 'eCounter' and the varvalue is the greatest.

The tables are relational by elementid one (element) to many (elementdetail).  I include the format of the actual elementid so you don't assume they are consecutive numbers.

I tried the following code just to get the Max varvalue/elementid for each call, but that did not work out either.

SELECT MAX(a.varvalue) as MAXvarvalue, b.callgui
FROM elementdetail AS a, element AS b
WHERE (a.elementid = b.elementid) AND (a.varname = 'eCounter')
GROUP BY varname, callguid

This is what I need the results to look like.

[image: 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the latest Informix version ( 14.10.XC1 ).

Assuming the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE element
(
    callid      INTEGER,
    elementid   BIGINT,
    elementname CHAR( 20 )
);

CREATE TABLE elementdetail
(
    elementid   BIGINT,
    varname     CHAR( 20 ),
    varvalue    INTEGER
);
```

Which are populated with your sample data ( OCR to the rescue, you really should post your sample data and tables as text, not images ):

```
INSERT INTO element VALUES ( 1, 1001901560322810000, 'set_Page1' );
INSERT INTO element VALUES ( 1, 1001921560322810000, 'set_Page5' );
INSERT INTO element VALUES ( 1, 1001181560322820000, 'set_Page4' );
INSERT INTO element VALUES ( 1, 1001021560322820000, 'set_Page3' );
INSERT INTO element VALUES ( 1, 1001331560322830000, 'set_Page6' );
INSERT INTO element VALUES ( 2, 1002281560322920000, 'set_Page1' );
INSERT INTO element VALUES ( 2, 1002301560322920000, 'set_Page5' );
INSERT INTO element VALUES ( 2, 1002881560322940000, 'set_Page4' );
INSERT INTO element VALUES ( 3, 1002271560322950000, 'set_Page1' );
INSERT INTO element VALUES ( 3, 1002951560322970000, 'set_Page4' );
INSERT INTO element VALUES ( 3, 1002231560322980000, 'set_Page6' );
INSERT INTO element VALUES ( 4, 1002781560323000000, 'set_Page1' );
INSERT INTO element VALUES ( 4, 1002891560323020000, 'set_Page5' );
INSERT INTO element VALUES ( 4, 1002391560323040000, 'set_Page4' );

INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1001901560322810000, 'eCounter', 0 );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1001901560322810000, 'other_variables', NULL );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1001921560322810000, 'eCounter', 1 );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1001921560322810000, 'other_variables', NULL );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1001181560322820000, 'eCounter', 2 );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1001181560322820000, 'other_variables', NULL );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1001021560322820000, 'eCounter', 4 );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1001021560322820000, 'other_variables', NULL );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1001331560322830000, 'eCounter', 5 );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1001331560322830000, 'other_variables', NULL );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1002281560322920000, 'eCounter', 0 );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1002281560322920000, 'other_variables', NULL );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1002301560322920000, 'eCounter', 1 );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1002301560322920000, 'other_variables', NULL );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1002881560322940000, 'eCounter', 2 );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1002881560322940000, 'other_variables', NULL );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1002271560322950000, 'eCounter', 0 );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1002271560322950000, 'other_variables', NULL );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1002951560322970000, 'eCounter', 1 );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1002951560322970000, 'other_variables', NULL );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1002231560322980000, 'eCounter', 2 );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1002231560322980000, 'other_variables', NULL );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1002781560323000000, 'eCounter', 0 );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1002781560323000000, 'other_variables', NULL );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1002891560323020000, 'eCounter', 1 );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1002891560323020000, 'other_variables', NULL );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1002391560323040000, 'eCounter', 2 );
INSERT INTO elementdetail VALUES ( 1002391560323040000, 'other_variables', NULL );
```

We can do something like this, making use of a CTE:

```
WITH cte_element AS
(
    SELECT
        e.callid,
        e.elementname,
        d.varvalue
    FROM
        element AS e
    INNER JOIN
        elementdetail AS d
    ON
        e.elementid = d.elementid
    WHERE
        d.varname = 'eCounter'
    ORDER BY
        e.callid,
        d.varvalue
) 
SELECT
    vt1.elementname,
    COUNT( vt1.elementname ) AS count_elementname
FROM
(
    SELECT
        tmp1.callid,
        tmp1.elementname,
        tmp1.varvalue
    FROM
        cte_element AS tmp1
    WHERE
        tmp1.varvalue = 
        (
            SELECT 
                MAX( tmp2.varvalue )
            FROM
                cte_element AS tmp2
            WHERE
                tmp1.callid = tmp2.callid
            GROUP BY
                tmp2.callid
        )
) AS vt1
GROUP BY
    vt1.elementname
;

-- Results
elementname          count_elementname

set_Page6                            2
set_Page4                            2
```

Still using a a recent version of Informix, using windowing instead of a CTE:

```
SELECT
    vt1.elementname,
    COUNT( vt1.elementname ) AS count_elementname
FROM
(
SELECT
    e.callid,
    e.elementname,
    d.varvalue,
    RANK() OVER 
    ( 
        PARTITION BY e.callid ORDER BY e.callid, d.varvalue DESC 
    ) AS rank
FROM
    element AS e
INNER JOIN
    elementdetail AS d
ON
    e.elementid = d.elementid
WHERE
    d.varname = 'eCounter'
ORDER BY
    e.callid,
    d.varvalue
) AS vt1
WHERE
    vt1.rank = 1
GROUP BY
    vt1.elementname
;

-- Results
elementname          count_elementname

set_Page6                            2
set_Page4                            2
```

With an older Informix version, without CTE's or windowing, so we use a temporary table:

```
SELECT
    e.callid,
    e.elementname,
    d.varvalue
FROM
    element AS e
INNER JOIN
    elementdetail AS d
ON
    e.elementid = d.elementid
WHERE
    d.varname = 'eCounter'
ORDER BY
    e.callid,
    d.varvalue
INTO TEMP temp_element 
;

SELECT
    vt1.elementname,
    COUNT( vt1.elementname ) AS count_elementname
FROM
(
    SELECT
        tmp1.callid,
        tmp1.elementname,
        tmp1.varvalue
    FROM
        temp_element AS tmp1
    WHERE
        tmp1.varvalue = 
        (
            SELECT 
                MAX( tmp2.varvalue )
            FROM
                temp_element AS tmp2
            WHERE
                tmp1.callid = tmp2.callid
            GROUP BY
                tmp2.callid
        )
) AS vt1
GROUP BY
    vt1.elementname
;

-- Results
elementname          count_elementname

set_Page6                            2
set_Page4                            2
```

I have no idea of how any of this queries will scale when you use a more robust data set ( hundred thousands or millions of rows on each table ).

I have not tested any corner case, for example, when a `callid` has 2 `elementname` with the same `eCounter` `varvalue` values.

Comment: Luis, Thank you for your response.  Sorry for the embedded images, I am new to StackOverflow and didn't know how to create the grey text boxes.  A little more details, I creating this query in Cisco CUIC reporting tool and I am pretty sure the version is 8.x of informix.  I will try the queries you supplied and let you know if it worked.  Just to let you know we are talking about millions of records, but the callid can never have an elementname with the same eCounter varvalue.

Comment: So, I found out that I am using Informix db 12.10 FC3 within the Cisco CVP Reporting server.  The cte option did not work, but I was able to get the windowing option to work with a few tweaks to allow for date range filtering.  Thank you Luis.